# Download .csv file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to download a .csv file and save it onto my computer. However when I run the script below, I am getting the error "Error: line contains NULL byte". What is it that I am doing wrong?

```
import csv
import urllib2

url = 'http://wildfire.alberta.ca/reports/activedd.csv'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
cr = csv.reader(response)

for row in cr:
    print row
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you're trying to download is in UTF-16 format, and the CSV module is not designed for that. You need to decode it from UTF-16 into some other format. For example:

```
import csv
import codecs
import urllib2

url = 'http://wildfire.alberta.ca/reports/activedd.csv'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
cr = csv.reader([x.strip() for x in codecs.iterdecode(response, 'UTF-16')])

data = [x for x in cr]

# Manipulate the data here

# Now to save the CSV:
with open('outputfile.csv', 'wb') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

If you just need to download the file, and not manipulate it, there are better ways (see minitoto's answer).

This is an example, and the newlines have to be stripped manually for this to work properly, so I'm sure there's probably a better way, but that's the main issue

Comment: @Rishav yes, my bad, copied my testing code in a run and wrote decode instead of iterdecode. I have fixed it now

Comment: Thank you!! one more thing, what would I do if I want to save the file on my pc?

Comment: the question was how to download, not how to print out

Comment: @minitoto Your suggestion is indeed better wrt. that, I didn't see the "Save it to my computer" and presumed it was just downloading to open at the time. Nevertheless, I will add a way to save the file onto the end of my soloution in case calculations or verification of the CSV need to be done first.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest way is to use [**`urlretrieve`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve):

```
import urllib

url = 'http://wildfire.alberta.ca/reports/activedd.csv'
urllib.urlretrieve(url, "activedd.csv")
```

Comment: don't forget to leave a comment if downvoting

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I've done. The lazy way.

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://wildfire.alberta.ca/reports/activedd.csv'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
with open('activeddData.csv','w') as csvFile:
    for line in response.readlines():
        csvFile.write(line)
```

Comment: don't forget to leave a comment if downvoting

Comment: `with open('activeddData.csv','w') as csvFile` in which part do you mention writing to file?

Comment: @Rishav `for line in response.readlines():` iterates each line in response, and `csvFile.write(line)` writes each lines in a new file called `'activeddData.csv'`